# MusicKit: Is there a way to map the MusicItemID between a Library object and Catalog Object?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, apple-music, apple-musickit

So I understand that MusicItemID is a unique object identifier so for one specific artist; they have a different MusicItemID from Library than from Catalog.

But if I'm trying to implement a feature that allows users to add UNIQUE Artists to a list, whether it be from Library or Catalog; how am I supposed to differentiate between the Library Artist and Catalog Artist?

Any advice or workarounds would be appreciated, thank you.

In this scenario, there is no way for me to identify that an Artist from Library is the same Artist from Catalog because the MusicItemID is not the same; so it's not possible for me to omit duplicates from the list as I cannot identify if they are representing the same Artist.

I've looked over the documentation but can't find anything that would allow me to do this sort of mapping to match Artists between Library and Catalog. Using name comparison also is not a valid option as Artist names are not unique.

Comment: Like you said, "*Using name comparison also is not a valid option as Artist names are not unique*"; you cannot determine if the Artist from Library is the same Artist from Catalog at the first point.